# Trying to do a simple login with phonegap to my existing web application

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, cordova

I have a very large operation web mobile optimized site.

I would like to develop a basic hybrid application maybe with phonegap to authenticate the users to my large web application, maybe with webviews.

Why would I want to do this you might ask? I want the user to be able to experience my web application in mobile environment and store their login and username locally so they don't have to login to web application as session expires after 5 minutes in web app.
Also the mobile app can simply add a tile to their device for ease of use.

I cannot convert the whole web app as it is too large. I use MySQL as external database and PHP/HTML/JavaScript. I have not been able to find any useful basic login examples with phonegap that both login to external database and store credentials on the hybrid app device locally.

Any ideas here? Authentication has to update/sync with hybrid and web application when user/password changes in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy you sure opened a can of worms on this one!

There are a few ways you can do this:

Use JWT authentication. Send the token on login, and have the lifetime of the token dictate how long the signin is valid, but ALWAY validate the token, and NEVER trust a token payload if the signature doe not match. This has the benefit that the session is alive for the duration stated in the token, even if the application is hard stopped(as long as you save the token on the device, and send it with every request).

As for the cookie approach, I personally had a problem persisting the session beyond the hard stop of the cordova application (meaning turning your phone off deletes the cookies). If this is ok for you, then jQuery's ajax has the best solution. In the `beforeSend` set `xhr.withCredentials` to `true`, and the session details will be sent to the server. But i want to stress that this session approach is not permanent compared to the token approach.

beyond this session stuff, just replacing the html code in a page with the content that you want to show should be enough in cordova. that means that you cant send the `<header>`. You must send just the stuff that goes in the `<body>` excluding the tag itself. all of this will go in your `data-type="page"` if you are using jQuery mobile

Edit: think of your cordova application as a web browser, not an application that MUST have all of the html on hand to be effective

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but The problem goes a little further . My web application already encrypts the data with mcrypt. AES for login password . I am trying to basically develop a simple login hybrid phonegap application to login to MySQL database and Auto - login to web app from mobile application because of encryption and permissions. I am looking for some basic code to do a post to my login.php application or make a REST application and connect it to my web application so permissions are synced.